# Bucle infinito al calcular años bisiestos en un rango

Tags: c#

hace un par de días que empecé con c#, y ahora mismo tengo que hacer un ejercicio que a través de funciones, me diga si los años dentro de un intervalo son o no bisisestos. Bien, el programa funciona hasta que entra en el bucle que lo calcula (El ejercicio pedía que hubiesen booleans en el for, ya se que son bastante innecesarias, pero el ejercicio así lo demanda), el cual se queda dando vueltas indefinidamente, alguien le ve algo?

```
namespace ConsoleApplication39
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int any1, any2, opcio;
            bool entradaValida = false;


            Console.WriteLine("Menú \n Opció 1 (Prem tecla 1): Comença el programa \n Opció 2 (prem tecla 2): ajuda\nEntra una opció:\n");
            opcio = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            do
            {

                if (opcio < 1 || opcio > 2)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("El nombre entrat ha de ser 1 o 2, torna a provar:\n");
                    opcio = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                }
                else if (opcio == 1)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Has escollit la opció 1\n");
                    anyTraspas(out any1, out any2);


                }
                else if (opcio == 2)
                {
                    ajuda(ref opcio);
                }


            } while (!entradaValida);

        }


        static void ajuda(ref int opcio)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nAquest és un programa que determina si els anys d'un intèrval són o no de traspàs\ns'ha d'introduïr el any més petit i llavors el més gran\nAra pots tornar a escollir una opció:\n");
            opcio = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        static void anyTraspas(out int any1, out int any2)
        {
            bool esTraspas = false, entradaValida = false;

            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Entra el primer any:\n");
                any1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.WriteLine("Entra el segon any:\n");
                any2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                if (any1 > any2)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("El primer any ha de ser superior al segon:\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int x = any1; any1 <= any2; x++)
                    {
                        if (x % 4 == 0 && (x % 100 != 0 || x % 400 == 0))
                        {
                            esTraspas = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            esTraspas = false;
                        }

                        if (esTraspas == true)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("El any " + x + " es de traspàs");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("El any " + x + " no es de traspàs");
                        }

                    }
                    entradaValida = true;
                }

            } while (!entradaValida);


        }


    }
}
```

Muchas gracias de antemano, llevo ya un rato dándole vueltas y vueltas y no lo saco

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Reemplaza en el `for`, en el punto en que se establece el limite del bucle,
2. Reemplaza `any1` por `x`

   ```
   for (int x = any1; x <= any2; x++) {}
   ```